# Looking up book title with ISBN

Tags: title, lookup, isbn

Is there a free way to look up the title of a book using its ISBN number?  I know there is [isbndb.com](http://isbndb.com), but they limit you to 500 look ups per day.  Also I noticed there is the Google Books API, is there a limit with Google Books?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the [Google API's Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console), it mentions a "Courtesy limit: 1,000 queries/day". There is nothing that states what happens if you go over.

Answer (score 3):

No. Google does not specifically limit the numbber of lookups. In the TOS they do use the standard laywerspeak, "Google, at its sole discretion, may limit the amount of Google Books Content it delivers to you. ", but I'm sure if you, "Aren't being evil", as they say, you should be good.

Terms of service: http://code.google.com/apis/books/terms.html (which read a lot like the google maps API TOS).

Comment: While not specifically an API this looks intresting: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:ISBN

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at https://sourceforge.net/projects/isbntools/files/latest/download.

Or if you are a developer at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/isbntools.

Comment: "This project has no files"

Comment: It was discontinued due to lack of interest!